# Populate a drop down box from sql query in a table and strip symbols

Tags: php, sql, dropdown, strip, populate

At present I have this code

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM garage WHERE PlayerUID = '$id' 
ORDER BY DateStored");

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;


printf("Player has %d Vehicles stored.\n <br>", $row_cnt);
echo "<br>";



echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Player Name</th>
<th>Vehicle</th>
<th>Date Stored</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='https://www.battlemetrics.com/rcon/players?filter%5Bsearch%5D=%22".$row['PlayerUID']."%22&filter%5Bservers%5D=2191805%2C2315320%2C2384537&sort=score&showServers=true' target='_blank'>" . $row['Name'] . " 
</td>";    
echo "<td><a href='https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Dayz+Epoch+".$row['DisplayName']."' target='_blank'>" . $row['DisplayName'] . " 
 </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DateStored'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletegarage.php?del=$row[id]' Onclick='return ConfirmDelete()'>Delete</a>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Which gives me this output :

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRY4H.png)

What I would like to achieve is adding another table after Vehicle field which displays the information from the database in the "Inventory" field into a dropdown list, but the current information that is in a single row looks like this:

```
[[[],[]],[["CinderBlocks","cinder_door_kit","cinder_garage_kit","full_cinder_wall_kit","ItemComboLock","metal_floor_kit","ItemVault","PartVRotor","ItemPole","PartGeneric","MortarBucket","ItemSledgeHandle","ItemSledgeHead","ItemTankTrap","plot_pole_kit"],[61,3,5,25,4,11,4,1,22,1,15,2,2,21,1]],[[],[]]]
```

so I would like to try and display each item in that list without symbols and on different lines within that dropbox if it's at all possible.

I would like it to look something like this :

[What i need the dropdown to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRlnY.png)

I hope this provides you with enough information as to what I need and would appreciate any support!

Comment: Please edit the tags and include the programming language you’re using so people can help with this

Comment: Added sql and php :)

Comment: Disappointed no-one has a solution to this :( Really struggling!